Show that $S_n \xrightarrow{a.s.} S$ for some random variable $S.$

Let $\{X_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that for some $\alpha \geq \frac {1} {2},$ $$\mathbb P \left (X_n= \pm n^{\alpha} \right ) = \frac {n^{1-2 \alpha}} {2} \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbb P \left (X_n = 0 \right )  = 1 - n^{1 - 2 \alpha}.$$ Let $S_n = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{n} X_j$ and $s_n^2 = \mathbb {Var} \left (S_n \right ).$
(a) Show that for all $\alpha \in \left [\frac {1} {2}, 1 \right ),$ $$\frac {S_n} {s_n} \stackrel d \to \mathcal N (0,1). \tag{$\ast$}$$
(b) Show that $(\ast)$ fails for $\alpha \in [1, \infty).$
(c) Show that for $\alpha > 1,$ $S_n \xrightarrow {a.s.} S$ for some random variable $S$ and that $s_n \to \infty.$

I can manage to show (a) by the Lyapounov's condition which is a sufficient condition for the Lindeberg condition to hold and then by Kolmogorov-Levy-Feller Central Limit Theorem the result follows. For (c) I tried to use Kolmogorov's Two Series Theorem but the problem arises as $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb {Var} (X_n) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mathbb E \left [X_n^2 \right ] = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} n  = \infty.$ Similar problem arises if one tries to use Kolmogorov's Three Series Theorem with $A = 1,$ as $n^{\alpha} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ for $\alpha > 1$ and hence eventually crosses $1.$ For $(b)$ we need only to check the Lindeberg condition fails to hold as it is easy to check that $L_1(n) = \frac {\max\limits_{1 \leq j \leq n} \mathbb {Var} \left (X_j \right )} {s_n^2} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and hence $(\ast)$ fails to hold only if Lindeberg condition is not satisfied by the virtue of Kolmogorov-Levy-Feller Central Limit Theorem.
Could anyone give me some suggestion on the last two parts? Thanks for you help.
Source $:$ Exercise $11.4$ of Athreya and Lahiri.

For $\alpha > 1,$ the Lindeberg condition fails to hold. In fact, $$\frac {1} {s_n^2} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} \mathbb E \left [\left \lvert X_i \right \rvert^{2} \chi \left (\left \lvert X_i \right \rvert > \varepsilon s_n \right ) \right ] \xrightarrow {n \to \infty} 1.$$

Lindeberg's condition is a sufficient condition for CLT to hold. It's failure does not ensure that $S_{n}/s_{n}$ does not converge to $N(0,1)$.
Instead, akin to what you did, if $\dfrac{\max_{1\leq k\leq n}Var(X_{k})}{s^{2}_{n}}\to 0$ and $S_{n}/s_{n}\xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)$, then Lindeberg's condition must hold.
Now observe that $s_{n}\sim \frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}$. You have noted correctly that $$\frac{1}{s_{n}^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\Bbb{E}(|X_{k}|^{2}\mathbf{1}_{\{|X_{k}|>\epsilon s_{n}\}})\nrightarrow0$$
If $\alpha=1$, then $|X_{k}|>\epsilon s_{n}$ is possible if $k\geq \frac{n\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}$
For our ease, take $\epsilon=1$. Then you have
$$\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum_{k=\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}}^{n}k^{2}\cdot\frac{1}{k}$$
If we just focus on the terms with $n^{2}$, then the above behaves like $\frac{2}{n^{2}}\cdot\frac{n^{2}}{4}$  which does not go to $0$.
And this shows the failure of Lindeberg's condition.
You can use part $(c)$ to show that $S_{n}/s_{n}$ converges to $0$ if $\alpha>1$
$P(|X_{n}|>0)=\frac{1}{n^{2\alpha-1}}$ which is summable in $n$ if $\alpha>1$.
Thus the Borel-Cantelli Lemma gives you that almost surely, $X_{n}=0$ for all but finitely many $n$.
This means that the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}X_{k}$ is finite as it has only finitely many non-zero summands almost surely. This is the same as saying $S_{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}S$ for some random variable $S$. But, regardless $s_{n}^{2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=n(n+1)/2$ which tends to infinity.
This tells you that $S_{n}/s_{n}$ converges to $0$ almost surely.

If $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb P (|X_n| > 0) \lt \infty$ then by First Borel-Cantelli Lemma it follows that $\mathbb P (|X_n| > 0\ \text {i.o.}) = 0$ and hence $\mathbb P(X_n = 0\ \text{eventually}) = 1.$ This is the fact you are using. Right?

But why can't the same thing be concluded using Kolmogorov's Three Series Theorem? It provides a necessary and sufficient condition for $S_n$ to converge. Right?

@Anacardium It most certainly can. Just show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X_{n}|>1)$ is finite. This is again true as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2\alpha-1}}$ is summable. Also note that $X_{n}\mathbf{1}{{|X{n}|\leq 1}}=0$ almost surely for $n\geq 2$. Thus the sum of their expectation and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E(X_{n}^{2}\mathbf{1}{{|X{n}|\leq 1}})$ are both finite as they only have finitely many non-zero terms.

@Anacardium But it is often wiser and more advisable to not approach all questions by means of applying some strong theorem. Obviously, as the theorem gets stronger, so do the conditions and they become harder to check. In this particular case, it was easily computable. In a more general scenario, you won't really have the luxury to verify if Lindeberg's condition holds or not. I mean, that is the point of Lyapunov's CLT in the first place, it gives you something which is easier to check. In all my time of doing probability, I have very rarely applied the three series theorem verbatim.

@Anacardium As for your first comment, yes that is precisely the fact that I am using.

$:$ My bad. I tried to show that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb {Var} (X_n \chi (|X_n| > 1)) < \infty,$ which is never true.

I am just curious to know. Are you a probabilist? I browsed through your answers in MSE and they are indeed pretty good.

@Anacardium Ah! Not yet. I am pursuing my PhD in Probability Theory though (in Random Graphs and Stochastic Processes).
